# ffmpeg using drawtext and select together

Tags: batch-file, ffmpeg

I'm trying to extract every 30th frame from a video and add text to it, and output as a jpg.  Here's the code I'm using:

```
ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -vf "select=not(mod(n\,30)), drawtext=fontfile='C\:\\Windows\\Fonts\\arial.ttf:text='test':fontcolor=white:fontsize=45:x=(main_w/2-text_w/2):y=1800:" -vsync vfr -q:v 2 img_%03d.jpg
```

The first frame selected outputs as img_batch3d.jpg, then this is the error message I get:

```
[image2 @ 00000146e59d0500] Could not get frame filename number 2 from pattern 'img_batch3d.jpg' (either set update or use a pattern like %03d within the filename pattern)
av_interleaved_write_frame(): Invalid argument
```

Please help.

Comment: Your command executes fine for me in Linux. Are you running this manually in cmd or is it part a script? It looks like the `%0` is being omitted. You have a trailing `:` at the end of your filterchain. Didn't cause an obvious problem here but you may want to remove that anyway.

Comment: I'm running it from a batch file in Windows.  I removed the trailing ':'.

Comment: When I paste it into the command line directly, it runs fine.  So, mission accomplished, but I'm still curious why the .bat file didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to escape the `%` in a Windows batch file, so change `img_%03d.jpg` to `img_%%03d.jpg`.

See [Batch files - Escape Characters](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php).